# Make a draggable split panel like the console of CodeSandbox

Tags: css, reactjs, panel

I would like to make a draggable split panel for an editor. Its behavior is mainly like `Console` panel of CodeSandbox:

1. When we click on `Console`, the panel is expanded, and the arrow becomes `ArrowDown` for closing.
2. The border of the panel is dragabble.
3. When we click on `Console` on an expanded panel, the panel is closed, and the arrow becomes `ArrowUp` for expanding.

I have the following code (https://codesandbox.io/s/reset-forked-ivebxf?file=/src/App.js) by https://github.com/johnwalley/allotment. It can expand and close the panel, but there is a conflict with resizing. When the panel is closed, we drag the border up, I would like the arrow to become `ArrowDown`. Similarly, when the panel is open, we drag the border down to the bottom, I would like the arrow to be `ArrowUp`.

Does anyone know how to do so? I'm open to other react libraries too.

```
import React from "react";
import { Allotment } from "allotment";
import "allotment/dist/style.css";
import styles from "./App.module.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toExpand: true
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <Allotment vertical>
            <Allotment.Pane>abc</Allotment.Pane>
            {!this.state.toExpand && (
              <Allotment.Pane preferredSize="50%">
                <div
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.setState({ toExpand: !this.state.toExpand });
                  }}
                >
                  Console &nbsp;
                  {this.state.toExpand ? "ArrowUp" : "ArrowDown"}
                </div>
              </Allotment.Pane>
            )}
            {this.state.toExpand && (
              <Allotment.Pane preferredSize="0%">
                <div
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.setState({ toExpand: !this.state.toExpand });
                  }}
                >
                  Console &nbsp;
                  {this.state.toExpand ? "ArrowUp" : "ArrowDown"}
                </div>
              </Allotment.Pane>
            )}
          </Allotment>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In both cases of "_I would like the arrow to be..._" - Q: When would you like this mutation to occur? When first starting to drag or maybe on `.dragEnd` or during the drag - etc.

Comment: @RandyCasburn `ArrowUp` appears when and only when the panel border is at the bottom and cannot be dragged down anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onChange callback function of Allotment component. My solution is as follows:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toExpand: true
    };
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }

  handleChange = (sizes) => {
    if (sizes.length > 1) {
      if (sizes[1] < 31) {
        this.setState({ toExpand: true });
      } else {
        this.setState({ toExpand: false });
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <Allotment vertical onChange={this.handleChange} ref={this.myRef}>
            <Allotment.Pane>Main Area</Allotment.Pane>
            <Allotment.Pane preferredSize="0%">
              <div
                onClick={() => {
                  if (this.state.toExpand) {
                    this.myRef.current.resize([50, 50]);
                  } else {
                    this.myRef.current.resize([10000, 0]);
                  }
                }}
              >
                Console &nbsp;
                {this.state.toExpand ? "ArrowUp" : "ArrowDown"}
              </div>
            </Allotment.Pane>
          </Allotment>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. When I drag the border up from the bottom, there is a quick flash (the border moves to the middle then moves back), do you notice that? Do you have a solution?

Comment: See https://codesandbox.io/s/reset-forked-ksir5o?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You can use the React ref. I updated my solution.

Comment: Did you check my solution?

Answer (score 1):

`<Allotment onChange={}/>` component has an onChange event to identity each changes. You have to make one trigger point (400 in my case or you can calculate as per window height) and change value of Arrow Mark

```
<Allotment vertical onChange={this.changeSize}>

changeSize = (e) => {
    if (e[0] > 400) { // use your desired trigger
      console.log(e[0]);
      this.setState({ toExpand: !this.state.toExpand });
    }
  };
```